# Incluir objetos de classe associada (ApplicationUser e UserProfile) - ApplicationUserManager e OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin

Eu estou com o seguinte problema:

Dentro do método `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` na classe `OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` eu estou preenchendo umas propriedades personalizadas para serem retornadas junto com o Token. Porém, o objeto da classe associada `UserProfile` sempre vem nulo após eu usar o `FindAsync`, conforme mostrado na linha abaixo:

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

Eu consigo incluir via eager loading o objeto associado da seguinte maneira:

```
await userManager.Users.Include("UserProfile").SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == context.UserName);
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

Só que eu penso que não está correto, pois eu verifico o username no banco antes de verificar se ele está correto (por causa do password).

Eu queria carregar esse objeto após usar o `FindAsync`, mas não sei como.
Como eu posso fazer isso usando o `user`?

Comment: Não há nada de errado com o `Include`. Não entendi sua dúvida. Você quer conferir antes se o usuário existe pra depois carregar suas informações?

Comment: Então, eu verifico se ele está correto dentro do contexto 
`if(context.UserName == null)`
    `{`
        `context.SetError("invalid_grant", "UserName field is required.");`
        `return;`
    `}`

Comment: Mas qual o problema em usar a linha com o `.SingleOrDefault` direto?

Comment: Bom, pensei que não fosse uma boa prática.

Comment: Não, não tem problema algum. Apenas faça as verificações sem expôr desnecessariamente os dados. De resto tá tudo em ordem.

Comment: OK, entendi. Obrigado!

Comment: Quer que eu responda, só pra gente fechar a questão?